# Search specific line in the text file, add to a predefined dgv

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, text-files, datasource

There is alot of topics about how to read for a textfile etc and I feel like I've read them all. But i havent been able to apply it to my issue.

I have a textfile that looks like this:

> ProductID,Product,CustomerID,lineone,linetwo,linethree
>   AABBCC,banana,K001,something,something,something
>   BBCCAA,apples,K002,something1,something2,something3
>   AACCBB,oranges,K003,something4,something5,something6
>   CCAABB,banana,K001,someting,something,something

I have a form (Form1) where i have a textbox(tbCustomerID) and a dataGridView (dgvProducts).

The thing i want to do is that i want to fill in the CustomerID in the textbox in Form1
And then i want to loop through all the CostumerIDs that is in the textfile and then show ProductID and Product in a predefined dataGridView with 6 columns. (ProductID and Product = column 1 and 2)

My first attempt:(from a normal class)

```
    public DataTable ReadFromFile()
    {            
        //Read the data from text file
        string[] textData = File.ReadAllLines("MyTextFile.txt");
        string[] headers = textData[0].Split(',');

        //Create and populate DataTable
        DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
        foreach (string header in headers)
            dataTable1.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string), null);
        for (int i = 1; i < textData.Length; i++)
            dataTable1.Rows.Add(textData[i].Split(','));            

        return dataTable1;

    }
```

Then in my Form1:

```
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dgvProducts.DataSource = frm1.ReadFromFile();            
    }
```

But this just showed all the items from the textfile into the dataGridView.

Attempt 2: (from my class)

```
    public string findCustomer(string CustomerID)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("MyTextFile.txt");
        string searchId = CustomerID;
        string actualId = "";
        string produktID = "No match found";
        string[] details = null;
        string line = null;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.Trim();
            if (line == "") continue;
            details = line.Split(',');
            actualId = (details[0]);
            if (actualId == searchId)
            {
                productID = details[2].Replace("\"", "");
                break;
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
        return productID;
    }
```

Then in the Form1

```
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string aa = tbKundID.Text;
        dgvProducts.Rows.Add(frm1.findCustomer(aa));            
    }
```

But in this way i only get one value from the column 2 in textfile because i cant return two values in c#.
I have also tried to read all the lines from the textfile and then divide all the columns and then somehow show some specific stuff that i wanted to show, but i couldnt get that to work either with the search nor with the adding to dataGridView..
This is my last resort so i would really appreciate help on how i should do it in the easiest way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Editing your first attempt:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvProducts.DataSource = frm1.ReadFromFile(tbCustomerID.Text);  <-- pass customer id       
}

public DataTable ReadFromFile(String customerId)
{            
    //Read the data from text file
    string[] textData = File.ReadAllLines("MyTextFile.txt");
    string[] headers = textData[0].Split(',');

    //Create and populate DataTable
    DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
    foreach (string header in headers)
        dataTable1.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string), null);
    for (int i = 1; i < textData.Length; i++)
       if textData[i].Split(',')[2].ToString() == customerId <-- add the row only if customer Id matches
         dataTable1.Rows.Add(textData[i].Split(','));            

    return dataTable1;

}
```

Comment: I now loops through the text file perfectly! But how do I take out column 1 and column 2 from the textfile and add it to a datagridview with predefined columns?
(I want to take out column 1 and column 2 if I get a hit on the search)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @monkyxyz for solving your DataTable method.

Personally, I prefer to keep things OOP as much as possible and find DataTables to be less flexible (unless the problem scope remains simple and static).

Another option would be to de-serialize the text file into an object, and pass the objects around as necessary.  I assume your comfortable binding an object to a DataGridView.

I'll leave out all of the code unless you indicate that you need it.

But to get things rolling:

- Here is a nice little [CSV (De)Serializer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566656/CSV-Serializer-for-NET)

Comment: Never heard of Seralization, i'm fairly new to programming. But i will check it out!

Comment: @Nisse Happy to help!  Built in serialization in .net is limited to binary (1's & 0's), and XML.  Because your working with comma separated values, I provided that other project.  No sense in re-inventing the wheel.  For reference: Here is a bit more on XML serializatation. [Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s.aspx), and [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links! I feel like this Seralization stuff is really confusing and the other answer i can't pick out two columns from the textfile and then show them in the predefined dgv. I really can't get it to work as i want =/
I hate to ask, but do you mind show me some solution in code?
(I have a textfile where i want to search for a customerID and then show only the productID and product that is in the textfile in a predefined dgv with columns)